# mutate a value in list of list

Tags: python, list

```
board = [['a']*3]*2
board[0][0] = 'b'
```

...then `board` becomes `[['b','a','a'],['b','a','a']]`

Is there a way to mutate it such that it becomes... ?

```
[['b','a','a'],['a','a','a']]?
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are initializing your list is causing the problem.

```
>>> board = [['a']*3]*2
>>> board
[['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
>>> board[0][0] = 'b'
>>> board
[['b', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'a', 'a']]
```

vs

```
>>> board = [['a', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
>>> board[0][0] = 'b'
>>> board
[['b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
```

In the first method, because of the way you are initializing it, `board[0]` and `board[1]` are **the same list**. This is the same reason you do not define default arguments in functions this way:

```
def f(a, b=[]):
```

as opposed to:

```
def f(a, b=None):
    if b = None:
        b = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is equivalent to something like this:

```
x = ['a', 'a', 'a']
board = [x, x]
```

`board` is just two copies of `x`. `x`, `board[0]`, and `board[1]` all refer to same python object, and modifications made to any of these "three" lists are actually modifications to the same underlying list.

Try

```
board = [['a'] * 3 for i in range(2)]
```

**edit**: If you want to use numpy, this is a potentially "cleaner" alternative:

```
import numpy as np
board = np.repeat('a', 6).reshape(3, 2)
```

Comment: +1 for the numpy suggestion. If you are working with 2D arrays for a board like this, it is almost certainly worth consideration.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to mutate it such that it becomes... ?

Yes, you can try using the [`range()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#range) built-in function:

```
board = [['a'] * 3 for n in range(2)]
```

**Demo:**

```
board[0][0] = 'b'
print board
>>> [['b', 'a', 'a'], ['a', 'a', 'a']]
```

**Why what you are doing doesn't work?**

Because the expression

```
board = [['a']*3]*2
```

is equivalent to:

```
board = [['a', 'a', 'a']] * 2
```

There, you are creating a list of `2` lists. In fact, both lists are the same, both refers to the same object in memory.